# When change is transitive and in which situations intransitive

Tags: verbs, transitivity, active-vs-passive

I'm not sure when exactly the verb "change" can be passive or not. With googling, I figured out that it could not be passive when you are talking about a change happening in someone's appearance, otherwise it could be. Am I correct?

And what about this sentence?

> Teenagers behaviour would be changed by hormonal imbalance.

Or

> Teenagers behaviour would change by hormonal imbalance.

Comment: to change something: an active verb. All active verbs can be made passive.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The title says 'transitive', the post says 'passive'. My answer is for 'passive'. Feel free to ask about 'transitive'.

The word 'change', being a verb, can be put into the passive. It would happen like this:

Active "Joe changed into his new suit"
Passive: "Joe was changed by the experience."

The passive is acted on by someone else, thus 'was changed by'. The active does the action, thus 'change' or 'changed' or 'changes'.